# gcloud kube-lego setup ssl issue

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, containers, gcloud, lets-encrypt

I have thrown in the towel after days of struggle. I wanted to setup a SSL container site on gcloud with kube-lego

I decided to follow the step by step [github.com/jetstack/kube-lego](https://github.com/jetstack/kube-lego/tree/master/examples/nginx)

I created a Secret for `echoserver-tls`

From `$ kubectl get svc -n nginx-ingress` 
I setup an A Record to point to the External IP address .

The echo server responds when i browse example.com

```
CLIENT VALUES:
client_address=('10.46.1.5', 45422) (10.46.1.5)
command=GET
path=/
real path=/
query=
request_version=HTTP/1.1
[truncated...]
```

But when  i try https://example.com i get the error

```
default backend - 404
```

My configs are exactly from [github.com/jetstack/kube-lego](https://github.com/jetstack/kube-lego/tree/master/examples/nginx). Am i missing an obvious step not mentioned/skipped

I do not know the details to share but am showing results from 
`kubectl describe ing -n kube-lego
Name:           kube-lego-nginx
Namespace:      kube-lego
Address:        xx.xx.xx.xx
Default backend:    default-http-backend:80 (10.36.1.7:8080)
Rules:
  Host          Path    Backends
  ----          ----    --------
  example.com

                /.well-known/acme-challenge     kube-lego-nginx:8080 (<none>)
Annotations:
  whitelist-source-range:   0.0.0.0/0
  ssl-redirect:         false
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From                SubObjectPath   Type        Reason  Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----                -------------   --------    ------  -------
  21m       21m     1   nginx-ingress-controller            Normal      CREATE  kube-lego/kube-lego-nginx
  21m       21m     1   nginx-ingress-controller            Normal      UPDATE  kube-lego/kube-lego-nginx
  21m       21m     1   nginx-ingress-controller            Normal      CREATE  ip: xxx.xxx.xx.xxx`

Please let me know if you need some more info/logs. to assist.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `default backend - 404` by following https://example.com it means that your SSL certificates installed properly and ingress did not find service to expose for your host. So, it used the default backend which responds with message `default backend - 404` for every request.

The problem can be in your ingress configuration. It should look somehow like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: basic-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"

spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
    secretName: echoserver-tls

  rules:

  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: echoheaders # your service name
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```